# how do use type-graphql argstype object as a parameter for sequelize findall?

Tags: graphql, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I use nestjs, sequelize-typescript, and type-graphql

I created type-graphql @ArgsType

```
@ArgsType()
export class TagArgs{
    @Field(type => Int)
    type: number;
}
```

and in my resolver, i create query like following using above TagArgs

```
@Query(returns => [Tag])
tags(@Args() tagArgs: TagArgs): Promise<Tag[]>{
    return this.tagService.findAll(tagArgs);
}
```

following is my findAll function of class TagService

```
async findAll(tagArgs: TagArgs): Promise<Tag[]>{
    return this.tagRepository.findAll<Tag>(tagArgs);
}
```

But Errors such as **TS:2345: Argument of type 'TagArgs' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindOptions'** occur at **this.tagRepository.findAll(tagArgs)**

how can i use ArgsType object??

Comment: When I remove TagArgs typing in TagService findall, it works well.
is it correct way??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `TagArgs` properties have the same signature that `Tag` entity class, you should do something like that:

```
this.tagRepository.findAll<Tag>({ where: tagArgs })
```